# google map refresh after submit form

Tags: php, ajax, forms, google-maps

i want to make my map re-initialize after submit a form. my form has a drop down menu, the drop down is use to choose a region that will be shown in map. i want to when form is submit, the page is still in there, but the map refresh and shown the mark. sorry for my bad english. there is the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function initialize(){
                var peta;
                var gambar_tanda;
                gambar_tanda = 'assets/images/enseval.jpg';
                var x = new Array();
                var y = new Array();
                var customer_name = new Array();
                    // posisi default peta saat diload
                    var lokasibaru = new google.maps.LatLng(-6,107);
                    var petaoption = {
                        zoom: 6,
                        center: lokasibaru,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    peta = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),petaoption);
                    var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                      content: '<div class=new>""</div>'
                    });
                    // memanggil function ambilpeta() untuk menampilkan koordinat
                    url = "json.php";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(msg){
                            for(i=0;i<msg.enseval.customer.length;i++){
                                x[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].x;
                                y[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].y;
                                customer_name[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].nama_customer;
                                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(msg.enseval.customer[i].x),parseFloat(msg.enseval.customer[i].y));
                                  tanda = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            position: point,
                                            map: peta,
                                            icon: gambar_tanda,
                                            clickable: true
                                });
                            bindInfoWindow(tanda, peta, infowindow, msg.enseval.customer[i].nama_customer);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

                function bindInfoWindow(tanda, peta, infowindow, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(tanda, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(data);
                    infowindow.open(peta, tanda);
                    });
                }
                function reload(form){
                var val=form.org_id.options[form.org_id.options.selectedIndex].value;
                self.location='index.php?cabang=' + val ;
                }
                </script> 
                </head>
                <body>
                <div id="map_canvas" style=" align: left; width:1000px; height:500px"></div>
                <?php require ('config.php'); 
                @$cabang=$_GET['cabang'];
                /*if(strlen($cabang) > 0 and !is_numeric($cabang)){ 
                echo "Data Error";
                exit;
                }*/
                $quer2=pg_query("SELECT DISTINCT org_id FROM gis order by org_id");
                if(isset($cabang) and strlen($cabang)){
                $quer=pg_query("SELECT DISTINCT cp_rayon_name FROM gis where org_id=$cabang order by cp_rayon_name"); 
                }
                //else{$quer=pg_query("SELECT DISTINCT cp_rayon_name FROM gis order by cp_rayon_name"); }
                echo "<form method=post name=f1 action='' onSubmit='\"initialize()\'>";
                echo "<select name='org_id' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
                while($noticia2 = pg_fetch_array($quer2)) { 
                if($noticia2['org_id']==@$cabang){echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[org_id]'>$noticia2[org_id]</option>"."<BR>";}
                else{echo  "<option value='$noticia2[org_id]'>$noticia2[org_id]</option>";}
                }
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<select name='rayon'><option value=''>Select one</option>";
                while($noticia = pg_fetch_array($quer)) { 
                echo  "<option value='$noticia[cp_rayon_name]'>$noticia[cp_rayon_name]</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
                echo "<input type=submit value=Submit>";
                echo "</form>";
                include ('json.php');
                ?>

                </body>
                </html>
```

---

```
 <?php
        require ('config.php');
        $rayon = $_POST['rayon'];
        $cabang = $_POST['org_id'];
        //echo "$rayon, $cabang";
        $sql = "SELECT distinct org_id, customer_name, attribute16, attribute17 FROM gis where cp_rayon_name = '$RAYON'";
        $data = pg_query($sql);
        $json = '{"enseval": {';
        $json .= '"customer":[ ';
        while($x = pg_fetch_array($data)){
            $json .= '{';
            $json .= '"id_customer":"'.$x['org_id'].'",
                "nama_customer":"'.htmlspecialchars($x['customer_name']).'",
                "x":"'.$x['attribute17'].'",
                "y":"'.$x['attribute16'].'"
            },';
        }
        $json = substr($json,0,strlen($json)-1);
        $json .= ']';
        $json .= '}}';
        //echo $json;
        ?>
```

Comment: do you need panTo(latLng:LatLng) from [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=en#Map)?

Comment: what do you mean? sorry i'am still newbie. first code is using to select latlong that will be show in the map, the process is doing in second code, but how make the map shown the marker after the process? i miss that thing.

Comment: please, paste your html code with this select here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I can't understand why are you including `json.php` at the end of your file, also it won't work for ajax, cause you you commented last line. I think you don't need to reload this page using `self.location='index.php?cabang=' + val;`. Just send a request to `json.php` using `$.ajax` (you already have it in your code) and on success update map with `panTo()` method (description [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=en#Map))

so the algorithm should be: `<select>` onchange -> `reload` -> `val` (you already have it) -> `$.ajax` -> `json.php` + `data = val` -> `success: function(data) {}` -> `var newCoor = new google.maps.LatLng(data.x, data.y)`->`Map.panTo(panTo(newCoor))`

Comment: thanks so much vladkras, json.php is using to get mark latlong for the map. self.location='index.php?cabang=' + val; -> is ajax for the combobox not for the map. 

the case is:
1. in begining, the map is empty with no marker and there is a combobox that used to select a marker(latlong). 
2. after submit combobox form, i want the map refresh the function, and get the value of combobox.
3. so the map now will show the marker that was selected before.

Comment: sorry for my bad basic, i can understand your algorithm .. can you exactly show me, the code and where i should put it.

Comment: i think, i solve this problem .. i use different ways .. another algorithm. thanks for everything.